# Cut Permanent Redirection

Tags: seo, redirects, 301-redirect

We had 3 successful business websites before but our previous manager combined all our assets into one through permanent redirection. Now, another manager came and he wants us to use the other 2 sites into separate business entities/business websites. Is it ok to cut the permanent redirection and make them separate sites again? I know it's a dumb question with an obvious answer, considering that it's a permanent redirection, but I want to be clarified from any of your experiences.

Update: Only the homepage is permanently redirected to our main domain. All pages are still cached on Google search even the homepage... Are the other 2 sites re-useable?

Comment: If you are getting successful business after combined then why you want to separate again?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Helping Hands. It's actually a business game we're trying to step to gain more slots on Google SERP on particular competitive keywords we can't seem to dominate at the top 3 ranks. Separating them might give us a better chance. You know, 3 is better than 1.

Comment: I understand but after cut redirection and set all separate , I will take time to give you great business because then you will have to do SEO for all 3.

Comment: As @HelpingHands alludes to, the changes you have made previously and want to make come at a cost. Any site owner should seriously resist mucking around with a site that is successful. You (meaning your previous manager) cannot just simply make changes because it would be more desirable as a personal preference to have a website a particular way. Often, managers create arbitrary mandates. You are likely making a good decision- research it, but make it the last major change of this kind. It costs too much in way of search users when changes like this are made.

Comment: I mean to say - I understand but after cut redirection and set all separate , It will take time to give you great business because then you will have to do SEO for all 3.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the content of the three sites. If the content on all sites are very similar and are used primarily to "game the system" and take up as much real estate in the SERPs, you will lose. Google is smarter than that and uses signals such as same IPs, logins, user cookies, etc. to tell that one company is trying to manipulate the SERPs. An example of this might be:

- ultimatetravel.com
- bestflights.com
- bestcruises.com

In this example, I could see a legitimate reason for wanting to break them up **but** as previously noted, it would be better for you in all aspects (SEO, workload, management, expenses, etc.) to house everything under one roof.